# Three.js camera lookAt without rolling?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a little game where a ball can roll around a square level. I want the camera position to follow the ball, but always look at `0, 0, 0`. Moving the camera `x` and `z` to the ball position gets me close, however, as you can see in the below animation (sorry for any motion sickness):

[image: rotating level]

When using `camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) )`, the camera **rolls** around its `y` axis (I think?) causing the illusion that the level is rotating.

**What I want to achieve is moving the camera and looking at `0,0,0` without the camera roll.** As in, when the camera moves, the bottom edge of the level should stay relatively parallel with the bottom edge of the screen. Is this possible / does it make sense? I'm having trouble visualizing it.

I created a [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/andrewray/pen/Rrorww?editors=001) that illustrates the problem. I've extracted the lookAt function into a standalone function so that I can modify the quaternion once its returned:

`function lookAtVector( sourcePoint, destPoint ) {`

And I basically rotate and position the camera by hand:

```
var cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3(
    radius * Math.sin( Date.now() * speed ),
    radius * Math.cos( Date.now() * speed ),
    5
);

var lookAtQuaternion = lookAtVector(
    cameraPosition,
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0 ,0 )
);
camera.position.copy( cameraPosition );
camera.quaternion.copy( lookAtQuaternion );
```

**How can I modify the camera quaternion to not roll this way, while still looking at 0,0,0?**. I've tried:

- I've tried setting the `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` fields of the quaternion to `0`, `Math.PI / 2` etc to try to force no rotation, but the results are unexpected and I haven't found a combination of manual field setting that works.
- I've tried manually setting the camera up vector (`camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);`) as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271672/moving-the-camera-lookat-and-rotations-in-three-js) but the results are the same.

**Edit:** Basically I want to remove the camera roll like any traditional 3d software camera, and like Three's OrbitControls. The perspective from bottom left and bottom right edges should look like:

[image: bottom left]
[image: bottom right]

Notice how the camera isn't rolled in these pictures.

Comment: You want the center of the view to be as it is right now. You want the ball to move around as it does right now. You want the ball to be "centered" horizontally as it is right now. Is that all correct? What would you like different?

Comment: I want the bottom edge of the level (the yellow boxes) to stay parallel with the bottom edge of the screen, as in undo the camera roll that's occurring.

Comment: So you want to replace the roll with what? Pan? You'd lose the "*always look at `0, 0, 0`*"

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Sounds like you want to change the position of the camera, not the rotation.

Comment: In the edited images, the camera is "below" the level looking upwards. If you'd do that you'd hide the ball. Try creating this scene in your 3D program

Comment: In the example images the camera is always looking at `0,0,0`. The camera is rotated to achieve that. It is pitched and yawed, but not rolled. I want to achieve the same effect, but you can see in my example the camera is rolling. It wouldn't hide the ball unless the angles are extreme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was resolved by changing the up vector. Unfortunately the codepen didn't show the right example code (I'm using a slightly different axis system in my local game). But If I changed `THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp` to `new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 )` then I get the desired results:

[image]

The full `lookAt` function with fixed up vector:

```
function lookAtVector( sourcePoint, destPoint ) {

    return new THREE.Quaternion().setFromRotationMatrix(
        new THREE.Matrix4()
            .lookAt( sourcePoint, destPoint, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 ) )
    );

}
```

Comment: Check your render() method: How many times per frame are you calling `new` or `clone()` and instantiating a new object that must be garbage collected?

Answer (score 0):

You should only modify the position of the camera (panning), not the rotation. The position you want is the original Y and Z you have, and copy the X value from the ball (assuming that the left-right direction is the X axis).

A diagram:

```
|   |
|   |
|O  |
+---+

 C


|   |
|   |
| O |
+---+

  C


|   |
|   |
|  O|
+---+

   C

O - ball
C - camera
```

---

> What I want to achieve is moving the camera and looking at 0,0,0 without the rotation

How would you do that? That means the camera can move only on the axis of its direction (Y).

Comment: I mean I want it to look at 0,0,0 without the **roll** of the camera* occurring.

Comment: But it has to occur, by definition. Because you only have one axis available. Or I really misunderstood the whole thing...