# How to calculate xyz camera position with xy angles and distance in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to calculate XYZ position (for the camera) from 2 axis angles (in degree) and a distance.

I tried to implement something based on [this article](https://andreasrohner.at/posts/Web%20Development/JavaScript/Simple-orbital-camera-controls-for-THREE-js/), the problem is that it needs the previous XYZ position to make its calculation.

For instance :

```
function calcPositionFromOrbit(xAngle, yAngle, distance) {
    // ...
}

// Front
calcPositionFromOrbit(0, 0, 100); // {x:0, y:0, z:-100}
calcPositionFromOrbit(360, 0, 100); // {x:0, y:0, z:-100}
calcPositionFromOrbit(0, 360, 100); // {x:0, y:0, z:-100}

// Above
calcPositionFromOrbit(0, 90, 100); // {x:0, y:100, z:0}

// Behind
calcPositionFromOrbit(0, 180, 100); // {x:0, y:0, z:100}
calcPositionFromOrbit(180, 0, 100); // {x:0, y:0, z:100}

// Under
calcPositionFromOrbit(0, -90, 100); // {x:0, y:-100, z:0}
calcPositionFromOrbit(0, 270, 100); // {x:0, y:-100, z:0}

// Left
calcPositionFromOrbit(90, 0, 100); // {x:100, y:0, z:0}

// Top Left
calcPositionFromOrbit(45, 45, 100); // {x:70.7..., y:70.7..., z:0}
```

*P.S. I'm not interested in [OrbitControls](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls)' solution.*

Answer (score 0):

The article you mention is about (first paragraph at the top of):

> This enables the user to move the camera with the mouse along the
>   surface of a sphere, whereby the camera always points to the center.
>   At the center of the sphere there is an object that can be intuitively viewed from every angle.

So you need to find point on sphere using spherical coordinate system. You can do it using following formulas (I assume sphere center is in poin c=[0,0,0] ) (source: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates)):

[image]

where r is sphere radius and angle θ is in [0, π) and φ is in [0, 2π)

Comment: Awesome ! It works ! I have still one little problem : If the camera pitch is higher than the top side (> 180°) the `camera.lookAt(center)` makes it turn around in the Y axis but does not flip it upside-down. How could I rotate the camera so it looks upside-down too ?

Comment: @Tot I think you can rotate camera around viewport center by change [up vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16372679/860099) `camera.up`. However It will be probably not trivial (reimplement lookAt function and use [quaterions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) rotation or use [this "implementation"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11665562/860099)?) so instead you can just not allow pitch to get values equal or greater than 180 degree.

Comment: "just not allow pitch to get values equal or greater than 180 degree" > That's one reason why I didn't want to use OrbitControls. x) Maybe changing the up vector after calling the lookAt function would work.

Comment: @Tot yes but this is separate question you can ask/find it on stackoverflow